# NVM Region not unlocking on SAML21 Flash memory

Tags: microcontroller, c, microchip, c++

I am trying to write to a specific address on my SAMR34 which uses SAML21. However, I noticed that despite first erasing the row te address is located in, the data was not being written. So I checked if the page is locked, and it does seem to be locked, but I can't figure out how to unlock it.

I tried following the instructions given on the ASF documentation page for the NVM module: https://asf.microchip.com/docs/latest/sam0.applications.asf_programmers_manual.atsaml21/html/group__asfdoc__sam0__nvm__group.html
I first execute the NVM_COMMAND_UNLOCK_REGION command with the address I want to write to. I get STATUS_OK back. Then I check if the NVM module is ready with nvm_is_ready() to make sure the command has finished executing. Finally I check if the page is locked with nvm_is_page_locked() which still returns true. The code I use is pictured below. Is there still some instruction missing I should execute first?

```
nvm_get_config_defaults(&m_int_flash_config);
m_int_flash_config.manual_page_write = false;
ret_status_code = nvm_set_config(&m_int_flash_config);

ret_status_code = nvm_execute_command(NVM_COMMAND_UNLOCK_REGION, 0x4000, 0);
bool isready = false;
while (!isready) {
    isready = nvm_is_ready();
}
volatile uint16_t temp = NVMCTRL->LOCK.reg; // all bits are 1

if (!nvm_is_page_locked(0x4000)) {
    // code I want to execute if page is not locked, but page remains blocked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it. I misread the documentation of nvm_is_page_locked(). It requires the page number instead of an address. Replacing `0x4000` with `0x4000 / FLASH_PAGE_SIZE` fixed it.